# C# Find and Replace Line Breaks in excel cell

Tags: c#, excel, ssis

I need import Excel file to sql server by SSIS. there is a situation. two columns in excel associate with each other.
  [image]

I can do find/replace in excel to replace the line break to some delimiter(say &&). Is there any way we can do the replace by c# code?
Thanks

Comment: Yes, but I am not seeing anything to key off of in your data. Are there more columns with a person key or something?

Comment: And by the way I would not find and replace, I would just use the line breaks as delimiters.

Comment: Yes there are more columns in that sheet. I just use the name  height, weigh as example. it could be no value, could be have more than 2 or 3 attributes in one Attributes Cell. But there are always has values to match those attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made the following spreadsheet to match your data and added an ID column:

[image]

Now back to SSIS, I added the following data flow:

[image]

Open up Script component and go to inputs and outputs and define your columns:

[image]

Go back to Script and click edit.

Paste in the follow code to read the spreadsheet and parse into your outputs:

```
public override void CreateNewOutputRows()
    {
        string fileName = @"D:\imports\survey.xlsx";
        string SheetName = "Bananas";  
        string cstr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fileName + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1\"";



   using (System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection xlConn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(cstr))
    {
       xlConn.Open();
       System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand xlCmd = xlConn.CreateCommand();
       xlCmd.CommandText = string.Format("Select * from [{0}$]", SheetName); 
       xlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
       using (System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader rdr = xlCmd.ExecuteReader())
            while(rdr.Read())
            {
                int id = Convert.ToInt32((decimal.Parse(rdr[0].ToString())));
                string[] keys = rdr.GetString(1).Split('\n');
                string[] values = rdr.GetString(2).Split('\n');

                if (keys.Length > 0)
                {
                    for(int i = 0;i<keys.Length;i++)
                    {
                        Output0Buffer.AddRow();
                        Output0Buffer.ID = id;
                        Output0Buffer.key = keys[i];
                        Output0Buffer.Pair = values[i];
                    }
                }


            }
    }
   }
```

Finally, the output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Keith. This is very helpful!